# Conversion of graphite into diamond

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, solid-state-chemistry, free-energy

> The standard state Gibbs free energies of formation of C(graphite) and C(diamond) at $T = \pu{298 K}$ are $\pu{0 kJ mol-1}$ and $\pu{2.9 kJ mol-1}$, respectively.
>
> The conversion of graphite [C(graphite)] to diamond [C(diamond)] reduces its volume by $\pu{2e-6 m3 mol-1}$.
>
> If C(graphite) is converted to C(diamond) isothermally at $\pu{T = 298 K}$, the pressure at which C(graphite) is in equilibrium with C(diamond), is
>
> (**A**) $\pu{14501 bar}$
> (**B**) $\pu{58001 bar}$
> (**C**) $\pu{1450 bar}$
> (**D**) $\pu{29001 bar}$

We know that

$$\mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}P - S\mathrm{d}T$$

At constant temperature, $\mathrm{d}T = 0$ and we are left with

$$\mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}P$$

But as the volume is also changing in conversion of graphite to diamond and the pressure has also to be increased, how do I integrate this equation? Please tell me if I'm going wrong.

Comment: Why not just use $ΔV$ instead of $V$ since the contraction takes place? You then integrate from 1 bar to the unknown pressure, assuming that $ΔG = 0$ at equilibrium.

Comment: But isn't the V in the equation dG=VdP - SdT the absolute volume of the system? Or is it the change in volume?

Comment: That equation is derived for the constant volume (partial derivative with constant volume). In your case volume changes, so this has to be taken into account too.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting it, can you please ellaborate this equation a bit because I don't know that there are partial derivatives in this equation too.

Comment: You need to apply the equation dG=VdP to the graphite and the diamond separately.  So, for example, for the graphite, $G_g-G^0_g=V_gP$.  At equilibrium, the free energy of the graphite is equal to the free energy of the diamond.

Comment: Thanks.. Now I got it.. I was applying that equation simultaneously for both which wasn't correct..

Comment: @ChetMiller how did integral of v*dP become VgP?

Comment: @satan29. I don't understand what you are asking.